# How to sign apk with jarsigner?

Tags: java, android, jarsigner

**I have upload my first .apk to Aptoide and the ask me :**

"Sign an apk for us.
This method is used to verify that you are able to sign an apk using the same certificate used on the app you would like to certify.

1. Download this apk.
2. Sign the apk. (more) use the following command to sign the apk
   jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore
3. Upload the signed apk

**How i can use the jarsigner for this?**

please explain the process in details

Comment: Even though you can do this, why would you do it? You are actually signing someone else's APK with your key, basically declaring that you are "responsible" for that APK and then giving it to a third party. What if that APK gets installed and does something naughty? It has your signature on it ... You are risking something here.

Comment: I created the app. It's not someone else's app

Comment: is issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

For signing apps, you can easily use your ide / android studio. You can use this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html
 And jump directly to Generate a key and keystroke for your first trial and error.

Comment: I have upload my first .apk to Aptoide and the ask me :

"Sign an apk for us. This method is used to verify that you are able to sign an apk using the same certificate used on the app you would like to certify.

Download this apk.
Sign the apk. (more) use the following command to sign the apk jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore
Upload the signed apk.  Here is the problem I'm facing... When I'm using the command line it shows enter passphrase but when I put my password and hit enter it shows jarsigner error. I ho

Comment: yeah, I understand. do it with ADT through the link I provided, it'll be much easier the CMD is error prone, there you have a GUI

Comment: It's not the thing. They give me an apk and I have to sign that apk. It's not possible to sign someone else's APK in Android Studio..

Comment: oooooh okay, than if you won't find a solution I'll try to help you at the weekend :)